# Get 3 most recent months (T, T-1, and T-2) in InterSys Cache DB

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

How do I get three most recent months ?
I have tried something as shown below just to get T -1, but it gives me wrong result:-

```
select  to_date(CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE())) as date),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Result:-

```
02/01/1841
```

Comment: You are just casting the month as a date, you need to add the day and the year.  SOmething like this may be better.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `TO_DATE` isn't a built in T-SQL function. Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Intersys Cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off asking the Intersystems Developer Community at https://community.intersystems.com/

However the following will return the first date of the current month and then the first and last dates of the previous 3 months.  I'm no SQL expert so there might be less verbose ways of doing this!

```
select CAST(DATEADD('d' , 1-{fn DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)}, CURRENT_DATE) AS DATE) as FirstDateThisMonth
,CAST(DATEADD('d', -{fn DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)}, CURRENT_DATE) AS DATE) as LastDateLastMonth
,CAST(DATEADD('m', -1,DATEADD('d' , 1-{fn DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)}, CURRENT_DATE)) AS DATE) as FirstDateLastMonth
,CAST(DATEADD('d', -1,DATEADD('m',-1,DATEADD('d' , 1-{fn DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)}, CURRENT_DATE))) AS DATE) as LastDateTwoMonthsAgo
,CAST(DATEADD('m', -2,DATEADD('d' , 1-{fn DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)}, CURRENT_DATE)) AS DATE) as FirstDateTwoMonthsAgo
,CAST(DATEADD('d', -1,DATEADD('m',-2,DATEADD('d' , 1-{fn DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)}, CURRENT_DATE))) AS DATE) as LastDateThreeMonthsAgo
,CAST(DATEADD('m', -3,DATEADD('d' , 1-{fn DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)}, CURRENT_DATE)) AS DATE) as FirstDateThreeMonthsAgo
```